# how to specify custom category (slug) in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, filter, taxonomy, slug, portfolio

I have purchased a theme whose developer dropped the project and is offering no guidance.

What I want to do is simply show the portfolio category "featured" in the homepage grid. Thought I could change a few things in the php files but nothing is working and I really need a better understanding and solution.

here is a breakdown of the code. I have replaced the portfolio_category with featured and added a taxonomy of 'featured' in the array. the theme calls for me to enter the Category Taxonomy Slug for the Portfolio and replace the default "portfolio_category." Didn't work for me, so I'm not sure where to put what. If there is another file you need me to upload, please let me know.

website: test.muralsdcproject.com

**portfolio_page_template.php**
Portfolio on homepage file

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Fortfolio - Portfolio
 *
 * @package Fortfolio
 */
    get_header();
   
 /**get_template_part( 'heading' ); */

    // get settings
    $style = erlbs_meta_data( '_erlbs_select_portfolio_style' ) ? erlbs_meta_data( '_erlbs_select_portfolio_style' ) : erlbs_option_data( 'select_portfolio_style' );
?>
<div class="section active-section no-padding portfolio-section no-gutter <?php echo esc_attr( $style );?>">
    <div class="folio-container isotope-container">

        <?php
            global $wp_query;
            $portfolioitems = erlbs_meta_data('_erlbs_select_portfolio_filter_number') ? erlbs_meta_data('_erlbs_select_portfolio_filter_number') : 12 ;
            $portfolio_column = $col;
            $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'portfolio',
                'posts_per_page'    => $portfolioitems,
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'orderby'           => 'date',
                'order'             => 'DESC',
                'paged'             => $paged
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <div class="folio-col isotope-item <?php echo erlbs_custom_taxonomies_terms_slug( 'portfolio_category' );?>">

        <?php get_template_part( 'content','portfolio' ); ?>

        </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
            echo paginate_links(
                array(
                    'type'          => 'list',
                    'prev_text'     => __('«','fortfolio'),
                    'next_text'     => __('»','fortfolio'),
                )
            );
        ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

taxonomy_portfolio_category

```html
<?php
/**
 * Default portfolio category.
 *
 * @author      EverisLabs
 * @package     Fortfolio
 * @version     1.0
 */

get_template_part('archive','portfolio');

?>
```

content_portfolio

```html
<?php
    $portfolio_format = erlbs_meta_data( '_erlbs_radio_portfolio_format' );
?>
<div class="entry">
    <div class="entry-media">
        <?php if ( $portfolio_format == 'media' ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo erlbs_meta_data( '_erlbs_portfolio_media_link' ); ?>" class="light-box play" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" title="<?php the_title();?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio' ); ?>
        </a>
        <?php elseif ( $portfolio_format == 'gallery' ): ?>
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                    $gallery_images = erlbs_meta_data( '_erlbs_portfolio_gallery' );
                    foreach( $gallery_images as $image => $image_id ) :
                    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, 'post' );
                ?>
                <li><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $img[0] );?>" alt="" class="img-responsive"></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php elseif ( $portfolio_format == 'lightbox' ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'full' ); ?>" class="light-box zoom" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" title="<?php the_title();?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio' ); ?>
        </a>
        <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="link" title="">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio' ); ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <!--/.entry-media-->
    <div class="entry-top">
        <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title=""><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
    </div>
    <!--/.entry-top-->
</div>
<!--/.entry-->
```

Comment: Does the post type have categories? If it does, try adding this parameter to the query. 'portfolio_categories' => 'featured'. depending on how the dev added categories to the post_type, portfolio_categories may be named differently. You should be able to find the name in functions.php. just look for 'taxonomies' => array('NAME HERE')